# Quotes getting stripped while piping

Tags: python

**Commands**

```
 sys_info_json = '"'+stamp+'":{"cpu_free" : "'+str[0]+'","disk_available" : "'+str[1]+'","disk_free" : "'+str[2]+'","ram" : "'+str[3]+'","memory_free" :"'+str[4]+'"}'
 print sys_info_json
 os.system("echo " + sys_info_json + " >> sys_info.txt")
```

Here stamp and str[] are predefined.

I want to save the data in JSON format.
While piping into a text file(sys_info.txt) the double quotes get stripped.

Comment: Please define "striped". What's that look like? Do you mean "stripped"?

Comment: Oh, I supposed you *do* mean "stripped". Well, you'd have to escape for command line syntax. By why in the world are you taking a detour via a CLI `echo`?! Just write to the file using Python code!

Comment: At the time of my comment, the question has been down-voted twice. The poster's approach is.. "exotic" (or plain wrong) but imo doesn't deserve down-voting. There is a clear question and even some code! Give the noobs some love please :-)

Comment: Escaping didn't work

Comment: Yeah sorry, meant stripped only

Comment: @Baxiz How did you perform the escaping? (e.g. Python 3 has a library function `shlex.quote` for this.) It is almost clear by now that the shell strips away your quotes as it is supposed to. Since it is possible to properly quote strings to prevent them from shell escape, there seems to be something still wrong with your code. So please show the actual code.

Comment: sys_info_json = sys_info_json +'\"'+stamp+'\":{\"cpu_free\" :\"'+str[0]+'\",\"disk_available\" :\"'+str[1]+'\",\"disk_free\" :\"'+str[2]+'\",\"ram\" :\"'+str[3]+'\",\"memory_free\":\"'+str[4]+'\"},'


Works well when printed, but the quotes are removed in the text file.

Answer (score 3):

Don't try and build up JSON by string concatenation. There is a built-in library for that. And don't write to a file via `os.system`: use the `open` and `write` functions.

```
import json
data = {"cpu_free" : str[0], "disk_available": str[1], "disk_free": str[2], "ram": str[3], "memory_free": str[4]}
with open('sys_info.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write("%s:%s" % (stamp, json.dumps(data)))
```

Also, don't call a list `str`, as it is a) not a string and b) shadows the built-in `str()` function.

Comment: Totally unrelated.. .But why are the field names appearing in a different order of JSON when printed?

Comment: Because dictionaries are unordered, you shouldn't rely on any particular order.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape the quotes if you want to see them in the system shell, something like this

```
In [16]: sys_info_json = '\\"test\\"'

In [17]: os.system("echo " + sys_info_json)
"test"
Out[17]: 0
```

Also is not a good practise to override python `str` with your variable. Try to define your variables with not used python words.